# Is there a Google Maps API for iOS which offers traffic information?

Tags: ios, google-maps-api-3, mapkit, traffic

I would like to know if someone has got documentation about the Google Maps API, ***I'm only looking for the traffic live information*** I would like to implement it on my iOS application.

Does such an API exist?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think Google offers a standlone traffic API as of now. However there are a couple options.

- Render the Google Maps element in a WebView and use the Google JavaScript API to enable the traffic layer. The downside of this approach is that the UX likely wont be as nice as native programming. The upside is less coding.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#TrafficLayer

- Call another traffic provider's REST API and overlay on top of the native iOS map component. This overlay is pretty straightforward through code if you get a KML response. The two I know of are MapQuest (yes, they are still around!) and Yahoo (though their API is in transition now).

http://www.mapquestapi.com/traffic/

http://developer.yahoo.com/traffic/rest/V1/index.html

Comment: Thanks man, that is great. 

i'm more looking for a traffic provider's REST API, i found the first one but it doesnt seems working in France... about the Yahoo's one where can i see if it is working in France ?  

thanks a lot.

Comment: Cool. Glad its helpful. Bing Maps offers traffic as well and it takes inputs in lat/long so it might support better international data for France?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh441725.aspx