# Bing maps API Traffic information

Tags: ios, bing-maps

I am running several apps that use Google Maps. On Android and Windows Phone it's easy to show current traffic information as an overlay on the map. But in iOS this is [not a viable option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821282/is-there-a-google-maps-api-for-ios-which-offers-traffic-information).

Recently Microsoft [has added](http://conversations.nokia.com/2012/05/24/nokia-brings-live-traffic-advice-and-geocoding-to-bing/) Nokia Traffic data to Bing Maps, and i am wondering if it's possible to use these maps including the traffic overlay on iOS? (via the [iOS map control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg191758.aspx)).

If you have any idea or pointers: greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Bing Maps Traffic tile data on iOS however the only allowed method of doing this is to use the Bing Maps V7 AJAX control with PhoneGap. This is actually the recommended approach for developing Bing Maps on iOS and performs well. Take a look at this [blog post](http://www.soulsolutions.com.au/Blog/tabid/73/EntryId/794/Bing-Maps-on-IPhone-with-Phone-Gap-Apache-Cordova.aspx) to get started. You can then make use of the [Traffic module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh312804.aspx) to pull in the traffic flow data onto the map. You can also access the [Bing Maps REST Traffic service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh441725.aspx) to pull in traffic incident data.